# Bootstrap-sass asset compilation on Heroku deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, bootstrap-sass

I am currently working on a Rails application that uses the bootstrap-sass gem to help style some of my front end views. When running locally, I have no problem browsing the views. After Heroku deployment, I receive the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/bootstrap-responsive.css")
```

Here is a snippet of my application.rb file:

```
# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
config.assets.version = '1.0'

config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Any thoughts as to how to get bootstrap-sass working on a Heroku deployment with asset pre-compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had my bootstrap import statements in my application.css file. By moving to a bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss file, my problem was solved.

This post helped: [Getting bootstrap-sass bootstrap CSS into production on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092664/getting-bootstrap-sass-bootstrap-css-into-production-on-heroku)

Answer (score 2):

Did you install the 12factor gem?  You'll need that with Rails

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#heroku-gems

Comment: I'm using a rails 3.2.13 application so I don't think this applies.

Comment: Oh, ok.  I remember I had issues with this scenario as well on Rails 3.  I believe this is what made it finally work: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile