# Bootstrap sass gem conflicts between versions 2&3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, bootstrap-sass

I'm using `bootstrap-sass` gem in my Rails project with version 2.3.1.0. However, when pushed up to Heroku, I'm getting the Bootstrap 3 styles. I inspect the CSS style and it indeed does say Bootstrap version 3.

On local, the assignment seems to be correct. But equally perplexing, when I inspect the CSS file, it says Bootstrap version 3 despite displaying what looks like the Bootstrap 2.3 styles.

I think at one point, my `bootstrap-sass` gem was using the Bootstrap 3, but when I put it back to `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.1.0'`, I'm getting this strange conflict. I really just want my Heroku app to display the styles correctly. Even though I'm pushing up my current local version to Heroku, it is still using Bootstrap 3 stylings.

Here's what I've got:

`Gemfile`:

```
group :assets do
    gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
    gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.1.0'
end
```

I've created a `styles.css.scss` file, where I have the line `@import "bootstrap";`Here's what it looks like on localhost:

[image]

Here's what it looks like on Heroku:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this worked, but I found the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092664/getting-bootstrap-sass-bootstrap-css-into-production-on-heroku) to work for me.

I added `*= require bootstrap"` right above " `*= require_tree .` in application.css.

Then ran "bundle install --without production", followed by "rake assets:precompile". Committed the changes to git and then pushed to heroku.

I've never had to specifically require bootstrap in the asset pipeline before, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your `Gemfile.lock` might be incorrect.  Have you verified that the correct version of the bootstrap gem is defined in `Gemfile.lock`?

Also might be worth just checking nothing is set in the Heroku env variable `BUNDLE_WITHOUT`.  See [the Heroku gem docs.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler)

Comment: Hum... the version in gemfile.lock was correct. But I followed [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092664/getting-bootstrap-sass-bootstrap-css-into-production-on-heroku) and it eventually worked for me.

Comment: Cool!  Go ahead and post that as your answer and accept it as you solved it! :)